# Delete Sierra installer from Launchpad

Tags: macos

How do I delete the "half-cooked" Sierra installer?  The App store and "About this mac" show that Sierra is downloaded, but I still have that installer hanging out in my Lauchpad.  How can i get rid of it?  Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is one more way of doing it. You just have to go to the Application folder, select the application and press CMD + Delete. Once you do this, the particular application will disappear from your launchpad as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove Applications from Launchpad One at a Time**

There are two ways to do this, one is through the Launchpad itself, and the other is through the Terminal using the command line:

Method 1) Using Launchpad – Mac App Store apps only
Hold down the Option key, and once the icons start jiggling click the “X” shown in the corner of icons that you want to delete. This removes the app from Launchpad, and does not uninstall them, but this is limited to apps installed from the Mac App Store. If you want to remove an app not installed through the Mac App Store, you have to use the method below:

Method 2) Using the Terminal – removes any application
Launch the Terminal and enter the following command, replacing “APPNAME” with the name of the application you want to remove from Launchpad:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db "DELETE from apps WHERE title='APPNAME';" && killall Dock
```

For example, removing TmpDisk would be:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db "DELETE from apps WHERE title='TmpDisk';" && killall Dock
```

Launchpad will automatically refresh, open it to see the changes.